# How to highlight row in ListView without onClick?

Tags: android, listview

I need to highlight a row in a ListView automatically, without onClick. What my app does is to have an alert(highlight) on a specific food item when a food product expiry day is below 90 days. I have searched Stack Overflow for a solution but all the highlights are implemented using onClick. I have implemented the onClick Highlight for my ListView (Which is not what I wanted) is there any way the highlight can be implemented automatically when the food item expiry day reaches below 90 days? Any Help would be greatly appreciated!

**When I clicked on the product Milo the highlight will appear, how do I make the highlight appear automatically on food items that are expiring in below 90 days**

[image]

**Here is my XML layout**

```
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/AddProduct"
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/Selector"
        />
```

**My Java File**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inventory);
    AddProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddProduct);
    camera = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.camera);
    AddProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Inventory.this, AddProduct.class));
        }
    });
    camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BarcodeCaptureActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, BARCODE_READER_REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    });

    mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    arrayAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    mList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("All Barcodes");
    final List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>(); // will contain list of keys corresponding to listview item
    database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            arrayAdapter.clear();
            for(final DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                String dateNow = df.format(c.getTime());
                String exp = snapshot.child("expiration").getValue().toString();
                String barcode = snapshot.child("barcode").getValue().toString();
                String name = snapshot.child("pname").getValue().toString();
                String q =  snapshot.child("quantity").getValue().toString();

                Date d1 = null;
                Date d2 = null;
                try{
                    d1 = df.parse(exp);
                    d2 = df.parse(dateNow);
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                }

                long diff =  d1.getTime() - d2.getTime();
                long hours = diff/(60*60*1000);
                long days = hours/24;

                if (days<=90){
                    NotificationGenerator.openActivityNotification(getApplicationContext(),barcode, name, days);
                    Log.i( "Item expring in: " , days + " days");
                    Log.i("Item's barcode is " , barcode);



                }
                else{
                    Log.i("Item expring in: " , days + " days");
                }

                String value = (String) snapshot.child("expiration").getValue();

                items eachItem = new items(name,value.toString(),Long.toString(days),q);

                arrayAdapter.add(eachItem);

                keys.add(snapshot.getKey());


            }
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            mList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {

                    view.setSelected(true);
                    String myKey = keys.get(i);
                    Intent intent  = new Intent(Inventory.this,Edit.class);
                   intent.putExtra("value",myKey);
                   startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

**My ListView Adapter**

```
public class ItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<items> {
private ArrayList<items> itemObjects;

public ItemsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<items> itemObjects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, itemObjects);
    this.itemObjects = itemObjects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    // first check to see if the view is null. if so, we have to inflate it.
    // to inflate it basically means to render, or show, the view.

    if (v == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //inflating the tex views from list_items.xml
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, null);
    }

    /*
     * Recall that the variable position is sent in as an argument to this method.
     * The variable simply refers to the position of the current object in the list. (The ArrayAdapter
     * iterates through the list we sent it)
     *
     * Therefore, i refers to the current Item object.
     */
    items i = itemObjects.get(position);

    //If i is not null
    if (i != null) {

        // obtaining a reference to the TextViews.
        // These TextViews are created in the XML files we defined.
        TextView ProdName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ProductName);
        TextView ProdNameValue = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ProductNameData);
        TextView ExpiryDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ExpiryDate);
        TextView ExpiryDateData = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ExpiryDateData);
        TextView ExpiryIn = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ExpiryIn);
        TextView ExpiryInData = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.ExpiryInData);
        TextView BarCode = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.BarCode);
        TextView BarCodeData = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.BarCodeData);

        // check to see if each individual text view is null.
        // if text view is not null (means containing the reference) , it will assign text/value!
        if (ProdName != null){
            ProdName.setText("Name: ");
        }
        if (ProdNameValue != null){
            ProdNameValue.setText(i.getName());
        }
        if (ExpiryDate != null){
            ExpiryDate.setText("Expiry Date: ");
        }
        if (ExpiryDateData != null){
            ExpiryDateData.setText(i.getValue());
        }
        if (ExpiryIn != null){
            ExpiryIn.setText("Expiry In (Days): ");
        }
        if (ExpiryInData != null){
            ExpiryInData.setText(i.getDays());
        }
        if (BarCode != null){
            BarCode.setText("Quantity: ");
        }
        if (BarCodeData != null){
            BarCodeData.setText(i.getQuantity());
        }
    }

    // the view must be returned to our activity
    return v;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in the adapter when you add the expiry date check if it is more than 90 days then give the color you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should use xml selector for background each item of `listview` with list item state. Full code snippet is given below -

Layout of `ListView` item `layout/layout_listview_item.xml` -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/listview_item_bg">
        <TextView       android:id="@+id/textForList"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10sp"  />
.
.
.
</LinearLayout>
```

Background for `listview` item `drwable/listview_item_bg.xml`-

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#66FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>
    <item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#FF666666" />
    </shape>
</item>

</selector>
```

And add the `layout_listview_item.xml` to your `listview` on your adapter's `getView()` method-

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v = convertView;

        // first check to see if the view is null. if so, we have to inflate it.
        // to inflate it basically means to render, or show, the view.

        if (v == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            //inflating the tex views from list_items.xml
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_listview_item, null);
        }

.
.
.
.
.

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

probably your item object has a field refer to the expiration date ( if reaches below 90 days ), so in ( get view ) method in your adapter you need to check that field in every item object in your array of items if this field reaches below 90 days then change the background color of the list for this item so it will be highlighted.